# How does bootstrap create the "Example" tab on divs in their docs?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I tried to look at the code but am unable to determine how this gets placed above the divs. Also, googling "tabs on div", "nested tabs on div" didn't seem to show anything relevant so my terminology is off.

[image: Example on Twitter bootstrap]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I imagine they used an absolutely positioned `<div>`.

**Demo:** <sub><sub><sub>[image: jsFiddle]</sub></sub></sub>

#### Output:

> [image: output]

#### CSS:

```css
#container {
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 100px;
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;    
}

.tab {
    background-color: rgb( 242, 242, 242 );
    border-right: 1px solid lightgrey;
    border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 0;
    color: grey;
    display: inline-block;
    font: 12px Arial;
    left: 0;
    padding: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

#### HTML:

```html
<div id="container"><div class="tab">Example</div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Just need to make it more aesthetically pleasing, but this is a great start. (My attempt -- http://jsfiddle.net/955bV/2/)

Comment: @dasickis I don't think you saved your attempt. Your link is the same as mine.

Comment: Saved it now. Silly... Anyway, is there a way to have this only show up on hover? Also, it looks much better on my page with bootstrap loaded. (new to frontend)

Comment: @dasickis You'd have to use Javascript to show the child `<div>` on a parent `<div>` hover.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this:

CSS

```css
.bs-docs-example {
  position: relative;
  margin: 15px 5px;
  padding: 39px 19px 14px;
  *padding-top: 19px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px;
  border-radius: 4px; 
}

.bs-docs-example:after {
  content: "Condiciones de uso";
  position: absolute;
  top: -1px;
  left: -1px;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  color: #9da0a4;
  -webkit-border-radius: 4px 0 4px 0;
  -moz-border-radius: 4px 0 4px 0;
  border-radius: 4px 0 4px 0;
}
```

HTML

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="container">
     <div class="bs-docs-example" style="text-align: justify;">
       <h2>Header</h2>
       <p>Paragraph</p>
     </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/MgcDU/2060/)

Comment: Is there a way to link the content (i.e. "Condiciones de uso")? I'm looking for a side tab that I can have people click for more information.

Comment: @dasickis Umm, with the method I've describe I think you can't. Use `thinkingstiff` solution for that.